# Google Admob interstitial gives error 'No ad to show' in iOS

Tags: ios, admob

Google Admob interstitial sometimes doesn't throw Ad it gives error 'No ad to show' and the 'isReady' state is false for interstitial, 'isReady' state is sometimes true. In India it gives the Ad with UnitID of App but for USA it doesn't provide Ad with same UnitId, interstitial 'isReady' state is always false for USA. Is the Admob interstitial generated is country specific?

Comment: check fill rate.. sometimes type of app , category has low fill rate and to prevent that you might want to use https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation